# BSOD when upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 10 build 2004 (errror 0xC1900101 - 0x40021)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, bsod, windows-10-v2004

I have tried to upgrade my Windows 7 machine to Windows 10 Build 2004 and it blue-screens at around 75% with the following error code:

> 0xC1900101 - 0x40021
> The installation failed in the SECOND_BOOT phase with an error during SYSPREP_RESPECIALIZE operation

I tried running the `SetupDiag.exe` utility provided by Microsoft and got the following output:

```
SetupDiag was unable to match to any known failure signatures.
System Information:
    Machine Name = Computer name
    Manufacturer = System manufacturer
    Model = System Product Name
    HostOSArchitecture = 1033
    FirmwareType = PCAT
    BiosReleaseDate = 20150821000000.000000+000
    BiosVendor = BIOS Date: 08/21/15 16:33:09 Ver: 05.0000B
    BiosVersion = 0601
    HostOSVersion = 6.1.7601
    HostOSBuildString = 7601.24384.amd64fre.win7sp1_ldr_escrow.190220-1800
    TargetOSBuildString = 10.0.19041.1 (vb_release.191206-1406)
    HostOSLanguageId = 
    HostOSEdition = Professional
    RegisteredAV = Microsoft Security Essentials
    FilterDrivers = FileInfo
    UpgradeStartTime = 8/25/2020 6:45:41 PM
    UpgradeEndTime = 8/25/2020 7:21:01 PM
    UpgradeElapsedTime = 00:35:20
    CV = mQUjfs8Cr0WhBycT
    ReportId =
```

I also googled around a bit to try to find a solution. Many people with the same error said the error lies with a USB dongle driver called `aksdf.sys`. I downloaded this utility: http://cbstechnology.co.uk/downloads/haspdinst_7.100.25990.1.zip and ran the included program to uninstall it, but when I ran `haspdinst.exe -info` (`haspdinst.exe` being the included program) it told me none of the relevant services or drivers were installed on my machine. So of course it is not possible to uninstall them.

I have been unable to find any more information about why this install is not working. What could be the cause, and how could it be resolved?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you upgrading? USB ISO or existing HDD? ISO install tends to work where in-place fail.

Comment: Existing HDD. You're saying it would be more likely to work if I burned a disc? Would that allow me to keep all my programs and files?

Comment: @Peter - No; Whatever is causing the upgrade to fail must be identified.  Using an installation media will also fail.  The upgrade process is identical

Comment: Make and model of PC? More than likely the bios is not new enough for windows 10 to be installed.

Comment: Motherboard is Asus Maximus VIII Gene, processor is Intel Core i7 6700K. The computer was built after Windows 10 was released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to update my BIOS. My BIOS was from 2015. If I had to take a guess, the problem was probably that I didn't have some microcode update and that was causing the Windows 10 installer to BSOD.

In my case, my motherboard is an ASUS Maximus XIII Gene. So if you are experiencing this issue and have the same motherboard, try flashing your BIOS.